# How to detect addition and deletion of text file (like git)

Tags: git, algorithm, text, replace

I made web application to edit diagram (like draw.io) using konva.
Now I can import/export text file corresponding to diagram and I planning to implement undo/redo.
For now I think I can store many version of text file to represent undo/redo state but it use a lot of resource. I think it more efficient to store undo/redo as text lines addition/deletion as git does. when I commit change I saw git can compare and detect which line I add or delete (modify count as delete and add new line). I wish I can use same technique to my project as well. Anyone know the algorithm name and how it work?

For example:

[image]

Comment: "I think it more efficient to store undo/redo as text lines addition/deletion as git does." But that is _not_ what Git does. It stores complete file states — not mere differences (changes) between states.

Comment: Git does not store additions and deletions to a file, but snapshots of the entire file -- exactly that what you want to avoid. But, oh, Git developers are not dumb: they did invent a method to store files that are mostly identical in an efficient manner, but it is not based on addition and deletion of lines.

Comment: May be I misunderstanding something. But I added the screen shot from Github desktop.

Comment: What you are looking at is typically called a `diff`. You can generate one using the `diff` command line, and you will find some language modules that can do this (e.g., Python's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)). But if you want to store multiple versions of a file like `git`, why not just use `git`?

Comment: @larsks let me check diff, I might be the answer for my question. I just need undo/redo (ctrl+z) feature for my web app not version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is typically called a [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff). You can generate one using the `diff` command line, and you will find some language modules that can do this (e.g., Python's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html)).